# PHP variables not equal

Tags: php

I am still relatively new to coding with PHP, though I am familiar with a few other languages, so I decided to fool around with it a bit.

Basically I have been playing with regex and Web scraping, and am working on a script to parse some information from a site.  I am getting the information fine, but when I try to compare the values in one of my arrays to a string, it is not coming up equal even though the values show the same and are the same data type.  Here is an example of what I am working with.

Here I am simply trying to get my values compared by retrieving a set of values from a site and then moving them to a 1d array.  Assuming that the value of array[0] = "Value", it should be equal to $str.  I have checked with gettype() and both $tmp and $str are strings, yet they do not register as equal.  I have also tried with current() values in my array (which would actually be better for my purposes) but it is the same.

What I actually need to do is locate a value in my array and compare it to $str.  If it matches, I need to set a variable to the previous value in the array.

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.site.com");    
$str = "Value";

preg_match_all ('/<td class=\"name\">(.*?)<\/td>/s', $html, $return, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

           for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($return[0]); $ii++) {
                 $array[$ii] = $return[0][$ii];
           }


            $tmp = $array[0];

            if ($tmp == $str) {
              echo "yes";
            }
```

Comment: you can try trimmimg $tmp trim($tmp) - there might be newline chars in there... could also have stuff in there that are htmlentitied (try rightclick > view source and look at $tmp vs. $str)

Comment: Shouldn't it be done in the loop? And what do you mean by " I need to set a variable to the previous value in the array"?

Comment: add `echo "'$tmp' == '$str'";` above `if ($tmp == $str) {` to see what is  being compared and there are any leading/trailing space

Comment: @Crayon Violent - Thanks, I tried trimming the value coming from the array but it did not work.  I tried trimming both of the variables and it worked... I guess the default value for my $str needed trimming?  Anyway, I am getting a positive for my check.

Comment: @Nabab - The loop was to populate the array, but the rest was just a simple check to figure out why they were not comparing correctly.  And my other statement meant that when I identify a particular value in the array (say at the 5th index), then I need to get the previous value (at index 4) to set it to a variable.

Comment: Ok, then Mario's solution should do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result handling is a bit off.

```
 preg_match_all ('#<td class="name">(.*?)</td>#s', $html, $return);
```

You will get the `(.*?)` matches in `$return[1]`. And you don't need to iterate over that. Just use:

```
 $array = $return[1];
```

And then you probably want to compare all entries in the result list, not just the first:

```
 foreach ($array as $i=>$tmp) {
     if ($tmp == $str) {
          echo "yes";
     }
 }
```

To then get the previous(?) value, simply access `$array[$i-1]` (in place of the `echo` above).

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that method for accessing the array value but I have been getting "undefined offset" errors.  That is why I was also looking into current() and prev() methods.

Comment: @jb11: Which likely means `-1` and that your assumption may be wrong. The compare value is found in the very first table cell, and there are no preceeding table cells. You should show an example of your data table to clarify your question.

Comment: Except that when the array is populated above, I can directly access the values using array[index].  I know that the array is populated, but when I use a for loop and compare array[$i] to my string variable, when I try to set my new variable to array[$i-1] I get the error.

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure how I fixed it because I just rewrote the code, but now it is working.  Thanks for all the input, though.

Answer (score 1):

`$tmp` will always include the `<td...>...</td>` tags in the code you are using, you probably want to replace

```
for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($return[0]); $ii++) {
    //Matches of whole pattern (not just 1st group)
    $array[$ii] = $return[0][$ii];
}
```

with

```
$array=$return[1]; //array of matches of the 1st group
```

because there is also no need for the for-loop...

Comment: it should also fix your bug :P